# Como fazer uma imagem de fundo preencher a tela inteira sem perder a resolução da imagem

Tags: html, css, imagem, background, resolução-de-tela

Eu tenho uma parte no meu site onde preciso colocar uma imagem de fundo ocupando a tela inteira, tanto com largura quanto com altura. Eu consegui fazer isso com css.

```css
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: url(../img/Banner-Site.png) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-position: 30% 45%;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Mas o problema é que isso acaba estourando a imagem, ou seja, eu perco a resolução e nitidez da imagem. Já tentei colocando a imagem num tamanho maior, mas não resolve.

Eu tenho um monitor com uma resolução de 2560 x 1080.
Testei colocando as imagens num tamanho de 3000 x 1000. E em tamanhos menores também. Todas as imagens são em PNG, salvas no Photoshop como arquivo para web.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Leia essa pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132 e essa resposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5505/132.

Comment: coloque as informações da imagem também. tamanho, peso e formato.

Comment: Eu tenho um monitor com uma resolução de 2560 x 1080. Teste colocando as imagens num tamanho de 3000 x 1000. E em tamanhos menores também. Todas as imagens são em PNG, salvas no Photoshop como arquivo para web.

Comment: Já usou um max-width:100%; ?

Comment: Ja tentei, eu colocando max-width:100%; a imagem some e fica tudo branco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você quer na verdade que a imagem ocupe o viewport todo? Se sim tem uma unidade de medida relativa, que é bastante usada no design responsivo. O `vh` e `vw`.

> Muitas técnicas de web design responsivo dependem muito de regras
>   percentuais. No entanto, medidas CSS percentuais nem sempre são a
>   melhor solução para todos os problemas. width em CSS é relativo ao
>   elemento-ancestal mais próximo. Mas e se você quisesse usar a largura
>   ou a altura da viewport ao invés da largura do elemento-pai? Isso é
>   exatamente o que as unidades vh e vw proporcionam.
>
> A medida vh é igual a 1/100 da altura da viewport. Então, por exemplo,
>   se a altura do navegador é 900px, 1vh equivale a 9px e, analogamente,
>   se a largura da viewport é 750px, 1vw equivale a 7.5px.
>
> Há infinitas possibilidades de uso com essas unidades. Por exemplo,
>   “sliders” de altura total (full-height) poderia ser conseguido com uma
>   única linha de CSS:

```
.slide {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**FONTE**:http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px 0;
  color: white;
  background: url('http://lab27.blob.core.windows.net/wordpress/2016/05/css-code.jpeg') no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-position: 30% 45%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro"></div>
```

Comment: Desse jeito deu certo @Gilmar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Muito bem explicado Gilmar !! Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Quero ajudar, mas preciso de um pouco mais de informação. Vi que você forneceu as informações sobre a imagem. Mas eu aqui mesmo com uma imagem aleatória da internet não tive problemas com o código e me pareceu normal.
Teria como fornecer a imagem? Ou descrever o que está tentando fazer? Você quer cobrir a tela inteira com a imagem?
Desculpe botar aqui em forma de resposta, mas não tenho permissão para comentar.

**EDIT**

Se for para ocupar a tela inteira, precisa ser em `display: table`?

Assim funcionaria:

```
.intro {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: url(../img/Banner-Site.png) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-position: 30% 45%;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Se a imagem for grande o suficiente, você pode substituir o `cover` por `contain`. Há menos possibilidade de distorção. O `cover` força a imagem a caber por inteira na tela, já o `contain` encaixa ela da melhor forma possível.

Pessoalmente recomendo uma imagem bem mais larga do que alta para desktop e uma versão mais alta do que larga para mobile. E desta forma use o `contain` para não distorcer.

**EDIT 3**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.intro {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: url(../img/Banner-Site.png) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
}
```

Essas tarjas nas laterais eu teria que ver na sua imagem, pois aqui não estou conseguindo simular, mas a princípio eu imagino que possa ser da margem criada pelo `body`.
Mas em questão a responsividade, por isso eu disse de fazer versões.
Você teria que trabalhar com Media Queries e versões da mesma imagem para se adaptar melhor pra mobile ou tablet. Talvez esta parte seja melhor você pesquisar um pouco sobre para entender melhor, mas o que elas fazem é adaptar o seu CSS para diferentes tipos de telas, como: smartphones e tablets.

Comment: Então @LeonVFX, fiz o teste aqui colocando o 'display: block' e tirando o cover e colocando o 'contain'. Alteramos a imagem aqui numa resolução bem maior, e salvando a imagem em 32 bits, png.
Fazendo desse jeito a nitidez e resolução da imagem ficou perfeito, porém ela não esta tela inteira, mesmo eu salvando a imagem numa resolução de '2800 x 1300'. Ele fica com as laterais com "tajas pretas"
E desse jeito também tive problema com o responsivo, quanto menor, menos espaço ocupado ele tem, sendo que eu preciso que ele preencha tudo, mesmo no responsivo.

Comment: E deu tudo certo? Só não recomendo salvar em png a não ser que vá haver transparência, pois pesa bem mais do que um jpg.

Comment: Fazendo desse jeito a nitidez e resolução da imagem ficou perfeito, porém ela não esta tela inteira, mesmo eu salvando a imagem numa resolução de '2800 x 1300'. Ele fica com as laterais com "tarjas pretas" E desse jeito também tive problema com o responsivo, quanto menor, menos espaço ocupado ele tem, sendo que eu preciso que ele preencha tudo, mesmo no responsivo.

Comment: Veja meu EDIT 3! :)

Comment: Então @Leon, eu testei aqui colocando o 'width: 100%; height: 100vh;' e voltei para cover ae deu certo. Não consegui colocar a imagem 100% nitida, mas melhorou pra uns 95%. E esta preenchendo a tela toda. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.